# iOS - Play song after 15 min in background iOS 8 & Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nstimer

An app I'm currently developing is going to play a song after a specific amount of time given by the user, example after 34 minutes. I do not want it to be necessary to have the app open, I want it to be possible to quit the app. The problem I'm facing is that the NSTimer doesn't work when locking the phone or just pressing the home screen. I have searched the web, but I did not find any solution that works with Swift and iOS 8.

Answer (score 6):

You could post a [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html). You can set the `fireDate` to be any amount of time from the present. The notification can also play a sound embedded in your app.

Comment: I don't think that will work, because the app is going to play a song, not just a sound (sorry for the mistake saying it was a sound, I corrected it).